# Prevnet footer to slide in Ionic 1 sidemenu template with tab footer

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 1 side-menu template and due to some requirement I have to use tabs footer.

Its working fine, Problem is that when we click on any link page is sliding from left to right and footer is also sliding from left to right. Anyhow Is it possible that when user click footer does not slide with content.

I also tried to keep footer as

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class="has-footer">
        ...
        ...

  </ion-content>
  <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top footer_tab" ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"  ></div>
</ion-view>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: place footer outside of `ion-view`

Comment: I have placed but still footer is sliding with content.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys, I made template structure wrong. Its working fine now.